# (Laravel) Call to undefined method FFMpeg\FFMpeg::fromDisk() OR Unable to load FFMpeg

Tags: laravel, ffmpeg

Call to undefined method FFMpeg\FFMpeg::fromDisk()
&
OR Unable to load FFMpeg

I'm building a web application to upload a video and store it in cloud. I want to get the duration of the uploaded video. I tried to install laravel/FFMpeg package. After doing all the steps, I'm getting the above error.

Comment: Please share a code snippet with us with your `use` statements and the exact context where you are using FFMpeg. I have a feeling that you are `use`'ing the wrong FFMpeg class.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is :
first of all you have to install FFmpeg on your device.
This video may help (https://youtu.be/IECI72XEox0)

then you should call this in your Controller

```
use ProtoneMedia\LaravelFFMpeg\Support\FFMpeg;
```

after that just go to your (config\laravel-FFmpeg) file in your project and change the defaults to the exact path in c: folder

```
'ffmpeg' => [
'binaries' => env('FFMPEG_BINARIES', 'C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe'),
'threads'  => 12,
 ],
 'ffprobe' => [
 'binaries' => env('FFPROBE_BINARIES', 'C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffprobe.exe'),
 ],
```

Then restart youre computer